# Has warning but program still run: Fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system

Tags: java, android

I see this warning:
[image]

This is the line of code make warning:
https://github.com/donhuvy/temp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/deitel/addressbook/DetailFragment.java#L126

```
// Fragment subclass that displays one contact's details
package com.deitel.addressbook;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.deitel.addressbook.data.DatabaseDescription.Contact;

public class DetailFragment extends Fragment
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    // callback methods implemented by MainActivity
    public interface DetailFragmentListener {
        void onContactDeleted(); // called when a contact is deleted

        // pass Uri of contact to edit to the DetailFragmentListener
        void onEditContact(Uri contactUri);
    }

    private static final int CONTACT_LOADER = 0; // identifies the Loader

    private DetailFragmentListener listener; // MainActivity
    private Uri contactUri; // Uri of selected contact

    private TextView nameTextView; // displays contact's name
    private TextView phoneTextView; // displays contact's phone
    private TextView emailTextView; // displays contact's email
    private TextView streetTextView; // displays contact's street
    private TextView cityTextView; // displays contact's city
    private TextView stateTextView; // displays contact's state
    private TextView zipTextView; // displays contact's zip

    // set DetailFragmentListener when fragment attached
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        listener = (DetailFragmentListener) context;
    }

    // remove DetailFragmentListener when fragment detached
    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        listener = null;
    }

    // called when DetailFragmentListener's view needs to be created
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true); // this fragment has menu items to display

        // get Bundle of arguments then extract the contact's Uri
        Bundle arguments = getArguments();

        if (arguments != null)
            contactUri = arguments.getParcelable(MainActivity.CONTACT_URI);

        // inflate DetailFragment's layout
        View view =
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

        // get the EditTexts
        nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        phoneTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phoneTextView);
        emailTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emailTextView);
        streetTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.streetTextView);
        cityTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cityTextView);
        stateTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.stateTextView);
        zipTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.zipTextView);

        // load the contact
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(CONTACT_LOADER, null, this);
        return view;
    }

    // display this fragment's menu items
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_details_menu, menu);
    }

    // handle menu item selections
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_edit:
                listener.onEditContact(contactUri); // pass Uri to listener
                return true;
            case R.id.action_delete:
                deleteContact();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // delete a contact
    private void deleteContact() {
        // use FragmentManager to display the confirmDelete DialogFragment
        confirmDelete.show(getFragmentManager(), "confirm delete");
    }

    // DialogFragment to confirm deletion of contact
    private final DialogFragment confirmDelete =
            new DialogFragment() {
                // create an AlertDialog and return it
                @Override
                public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle bundle) {
                    // create a new AlertDialog Builder
                     AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                    builder.setTitle(R.string.confirm_title);
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.confirm_message);

                    // provide an OK button that simply dismisses the dialog
                    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_delete,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(
                                        DialogInterface dialog, int button) {

                                    // use Activity's ContentResolver to invoke
                                    // delete on the AddressBookContentProvider
                                    getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(
                                            contactUri, null, null);
                                    listener.onContactDeleted(); // notify listener
                                }
                            }
                    );

                    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.button_cancel, null);
                    return builder.create(); // return the AlertDialog
                }
            };

    // called by LoaderManager to create a Loader
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        // create an appropriate CursorLoader based on the id argument;
        // only one Loader in this fragment, so the switch is unnecessary
        CursorLoader cursorLoader;

        switch (id) {
            case CONTACT_LOADER:
                cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                        contactUri, // Uri of contact to display
                        null, // null projection returns all columns
                        null, // null selection returns all rows
                        null, // no selection arguments
                        null); // sort order
                break;
            default:
                cursorLoader = null;
                break;
        }

        return cursorLoader;
    }

    // called by LoaderManager when loading completes
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        // if the contact exists in the database, display its data
        if (data != null && data.moveToFirst()) {
            // get the column index for each data item
            int nameIndex = data.getColumnIndex(Contact.COLUMN_NAME);
            int phoneIndex = data.getColumnIndex(Contact.COLUMN_PHONE);
            int emailIndex = data.getColumnIndex(Contact.COLUMN_EMAIL);
            int streetIndex = data.getColumnIndex(Contact.COLUMN_STREET);
            int cityIndex = data.getColumnIndex(Contact.COLUMN_CITY);
            int stateIndex = data.getColumnIndex(Contact.COLUMN_STATE);
            int zipIndex = data.getColumnIndex(Contact.COLUMN_ZIP);

            // fill TextViews with the retrieved data
            nameTextView.setText(data.getString(nameIndex));
            phoneTextView.setText(data.getString(phoneIndex));
            emailTextView.setText(data.getString(emailIndex));
            streetTextView.setText(data.getString(streetIndex));
            cityTextView.setText(data.getString(cityIndex));
            stateTextView.setText(data.getString(stateIndex));
            zipTextView.setText(data.getString(zipIndex));
        }
    }

    // called by LoaderManager when the Loader is being reset
    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    }
}
```

Help me fix this warning

Comment: Help us help you by not posting pictures of text. Instead put the required code and error message into your question.

Comment: Why do you need a DialogFragment at all? You can make a `new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())` directly within the Fragment class

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggested, every fragment should have an empty constructor, that will be used by the system to recreate the fragment, if the app is moved to background/foreground.

In your case, you are using an inner class and you directly call the empty constructor.

It's not wrong, but in order to prevent wrong usage of fragment constructors, in which you set parameters to the fragment and those parameters are lost when the fragment is recreated by the system, I think the lint raise this warning, just to make sure you understand that it might be risky to use a fragment like that.

FYI: Here's a demo on how to use it in the "lint" way :)) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Answer (score 0):

On the same lines as @danypata, you need the  constructor to be accessible when the fragment is recreated. I think you have to make it static to get rid of the warning and make proper use of the fragments.

Answer (score 0):

I would have just done this. No need for the `DialogFragment`

```
private void deleteContact() {
     AlertDialog.Builder builder =
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
    .setTitle(R.string.confirm_title)
    .setMessage(R.string.confirm_message)
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.button_delete,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(
                    DialogInterface dialog, int button) {

                // use Activity's ContentResolver to invoke
                // delete on the AddressBookContentProvider
                getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(
                        contactUri, null, null);
                listener.onContactDeleted(); // notify listener
            }
        }
    ).setNegativeButton(R.string.button_cancel, null)
    .create();
}
```